# Does JavaScript take local decimal separators into account?

Tags: javascript, localization

I've got a web page that displays decimals in a user's localized format, like so:

- English: `7.75`
- Dutch: `7,75`

If I add two number variables together in JavaScript on my machine (where the numbers are taken from strings in the above formats) I get the following results:

- English: `7.75 + 7.75 = 15.5`
- Dutch: `7,75 + 7,75 = 0`

If I was to run this code on a Dutch users machine, should I expect the English-formatted addition to return `0`, and the Dutch-formatted addition to return `15,5`?

In short: Does the JavaScript calculation use local decimal separators in its string to number conversions?

Comment: `7,75 + 7,75` should actually return `75`

Comment: @Amberlamps: I'm not sure I want to know why...

Comment: I am wondering, why `7,75 + 7,75` returns `0` in your case. If `7,75` is a string, it should return `7,757,75`. If it is all integers, it should return `75`

Comment: It isn't inconceivable that the code is bailing out, leaving my variable at its initialised value of `0`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the separator is always a dot (.) in a javascript `Number`. So `7,75` evaluates to `75`, because a `,` invokes left to right evaluation (try it in a console: `x=1,x+=1,alert(x)`, or more to the point `var x=(7,75); alert(x);`). If you want to convert a Dutch (well, not only Dutch, let's say *Continental* European) formatted value, it should be a `String`. You could write an extension to the `String` prototype, something like:

```
String.prototype.toFloat = function(){
      return parseFloat(this.replace(/,(\d+)$/,'.$1'));
};
//usage
'7,75'.toFloat()+'7,75'.toFloat(); //=> 15.5
```

Note, if the browser supports it you can use `Number.toLocaleString`

```js
console.log((3.32).toLocaleString("nl-NL"));
console.log((3.32).toLocaleString("en-UK"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: 'Continental European' as we call it. ;) It's `.` in English English as well as US English.

Comment: So this will only work as long as the digits themselves are represented using the ASCII codes.  I was just reading up on Number.prototype.toLocaleString and found that it is able to format the number using digits from the script associated with the selected locale.

Answer (score 24):

Here's an example for a locale aware number parser:

```
function parseLocaleNumber(stringNumber, locale) {
    var thousandSeparator = Intl.NumberFormat(locale).format(11111).replace(/\p{Number}/gu, '');
    var decimalSeparator = Intl.NumberFormat(locale).format(1.1).replace(/\p{Number}/gu, '');

    return parseFloat(stringNumber
        .replace(new RegExp('\\' + thousandSeparator, 'g'), '')
        .replace(new RegExp('\\' + decimalSeparator), '.')
    );
}
```

It uses the passed locale (or the current locale of the browser if locale parameter is undefined) to replace thousand and decimal separators.

With a German locale setting

```
var n = parseLocaleNumber('1.000.045,22');
```

`n` will be equal to `1000045.22`.

**Update:**

- Addressed Pointy's comment by using the regex class `\p{Number}` for removing digits. So that it also works with non-arabic digits.
- Addressed Orion Adrian's comment to support languages where numbers are separated at every fourth digits.
- Added locale parameter to sepcify different locales for parsing.

Comment: Awesome!  Here's a modified version that works for React Native: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243865/how-can-i-determine-the-decimal-and-thousands-separator-format-for-the-current-l/56243866#56243866

Comment: `Intl.NumberFormat("bn-bn").format(123456)` — the problem is more complicated than just determining the separators.

Comment: Certain languages use 4-digit groups so (1111) should be expanded to cover that, see: https://www.statisticalconsultants.co.nz/blog/how-the-world-separates-its-digits.html

Comment: Some cultures use a space for a thousand separator, but both Firefox and Chrome use U+202F (Narrow No-Break Space/NNBSP) for this which I wouldn't expect a user to. "1 234,56" is a common way to enter a number but this will be parsed as "1"

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on the solution from @naitsirch we can use [Intl.NumberFormat.formatToParts()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/formatToParts) to have JS parse the group and decimal separators.

```js
function parseLocaleNumber(stringNumber) {
  let num = 123456.789,
    fmt_local = new Intl.NumberFormat(),
    parts_local = fmt_local.formatToParts(num),
    group = '',
    decimal = '';

  parts_local.forEach(function(i) {
    switch (i.type) {
      case 'group':
        group = i.value;
        break;
      case 'decimal':
        decimal = i.value;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });

  return parseFloat(stringNumber
    .replace(new RegExp('\\' + group, 'g'), '')
    .replace(new RegExp('\\' + decimal), '.')
  );
}

//replace this string with a number formatted for your locale
console.log(parseLocaleNumber("987,654,321.01"));
//output for "en" locale: 987654321.01
```

Comment: This a great answer. Uses regex, yes, but swaps out the correct symbols using the built in locale stuff! Works great with `en-IN`, `de-DE` which are my go-tos for testing number locales.

Comment: Sadly, IE 11 continues to be the bane of my existence since it doesn't support `formatToParts`.

Comment: Are there any cultures without a grouping separator? That's one thing I might check. Sadly this, and all the other answers, only deals with Arabic numerals.

Comment: @OrionAdrian Try the polyfill linked from MDN: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-formatToParts

Comment: This may need some additional functionality maybe needed in the case of CHF since this isn't taking into account currency formats where the currency format differs from the non-currency one.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the solution from @OXiGEN we can use [Intl.NumberFormat.formatToParts()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/formatToParts) to extract also the currency symbol :)

```js
function parseLocaleNumber(stringNumber, locale, currency_code) {
  let num = 123456.789,
    fmt_local = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: currency_code
    }),
    parts_local = fmt_local.formatToParts(num),
    group = '',
    decimal = '',
    currency = '';

  // separators
  parts_local.forEach(function(i) {
    //console.log(i.type + ':' + i.value);
    switch (i.type) {
      case 'group':
        group = i.value;
        break;
      case 'decimal':
        decimal = i.value;
        break;
      case 'currency':
        currency = i.value;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });

  return parseFloat(stringNumber
    .replace(new RegExp('\\' + group, 'g'), '')
    .replace(new RegExp('\\' + decimal), '.')
    .replace(new RegExp('\\' + currency, 'g'), '')
  );
}

//replace inputs with a number formatted for your locale, your locale code, your currency code
console.log(parseLocaleNumber('$987,654,321.01', 'en', 'USD'));
//output for "en" locale and "USD" code: 987654321.01
```

Answer (score 2):

No, comma (`,`) is an operator having special meaning, just like dot (`.`). Otherwise things as simple as:

```
var array1 = [1,2];
var array2 = [1.2];
```

would break under different locales. All mainstream languages I know treat `.` and `,` separately and stricly, irrespective to locale.

Answer (score 1):

No, decimal separators are not localized at all in JavaScript, and parseFloat() parses numbers in the same format as you need to use in JavaScript source code: “.” as decimal separator, no group (thousands) separator, “E” or “e” as “times ten to power” symbol, and Ascii hyphen “-” as minus sign.

To read or write numbers in localized format, you need something else. I would recommend the Globalize.js library, unless you can limit yourself to the single issue of decimal separator and a limited number of languages—in that case, it might be simpler to do just string manipulation that maps “.” to “,” on output and vice versa on input.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the symbol into account, this works in all cases:

```
parseLocaleNumber: function ( stringNumber ) 
{
    let thousandSeparator = (11111).toLocaleString().replace(/1/g, '');
    let decimalSeparator = (1.1).toLocaleString().replace(/1/g, '');
    let symbol = (0).toLocaleString()
        .replace(/0/g, '')
        .replace(new RegExp('\\' + decimalSeparator), '.')
        .trim();

    return parseFloat(
        stringNumber
            .replace(new RegExp('\\' + thousandSeparator, 'g'), '')
            .replace(new RegExp('\\' + decimalSeparator), '.')
            .replace(new RegExp( symbol ), '')
    );
}
```

2 details highlighted:

1. use 11111 instead of 1111 because the first always shows thousand separator by default.
2. Number format always uses '.' as decimal separator

Answer (score 0):

Based on the excellent answer from @stollr. Adjusted to normalise whitespace where browsers recognise `U+202F` (Narrow No-Break Space) as the thousand separator but users would more typically use a regular space.

```
 function parseLocaleNumber(stringNumber, locale) {
    var thousandSeparator = Intl.NumberFormat(locale).format(11111).replace(/\p{Number}/gu, '').replace(/\s+/g, " ");
    var decimalSeparator = Intl.NumberFormat(locale).format(1.1).replace(/\p{Number}/gu, '');

    return parseFloat(stringNumber.replace(/\s+/g, " ")
        .replace(new RegExp('\\' + thousandSeparator, 'g'), '')
        .replace(new RegExp('\\' + decimalSeparator), '.')
    );
}


parseLocaleNumber('1 234,56', 'fr-FR') // returns 1234.56;
```

Comment: Although browsers currently seem to consistently use `U+202F` this method supports any whitespace character from the browser, or on the input.