# How to make Javascript "toString" implicite method culture aware

Tags: javascript, internationalization, tostring, culture

in my ASP.NET MVC project, I need to make the JavaScript *implicite string representation* to be *current culture aware*, in particular with decimal separators.
For example:

```
var nbr = 12.25;
console.log(nbr);
```

Here, the `console.log(nbr)` must display "12.25" in EN-US and "12,25" in fr-FR, without having to explicitly call the toString() method.

Does anyone know a way to accomplish this please?

Comment: `console.log` does not perform `.toString()` implicitly, since its solely purpose is to output data as-is.

Comment: Ok, sorry, my explanation/example wasn't the best... What I want to have more generally is that the visual representation of a number in JavaScript into the final HTML is aware to the current culture without having to explicitly call the toString () method of this number.

Comment: So how number is supposed to know that in one case it must be treated as an internationalized string, and in another case as a proper number?

Comment: so how do we decide which to be used when without telling javascript?

Comment: I don't really know (I had a +/- basic usage of JavaScript until now, without having to think about that type of problem). When he is written/injected into the final Html (hypothetical). It is entirely possible I'm missing something in my JS comprehension that makes me astray about this need :(

Comment: The problem is that this is a number and will be treated as such and using a comma or a dot changes the value of this number so this is kept separate. So you have to change it to a string and than the value is just a string and nothing else.  "12.25" and "12,25" in string format just means that these are letters so it doesn't affect anything else.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004808/does-javascript-take-local-decimal-separators-into-account

Comment: Ok, thanks! I understand and that's what I was afraid :( So, I 'll probably come back to the good old Globalize.js to accomplish that.

Comment: Numbers are worldwide represented using the dot as a decimal separator, it's not like in France you must use a comma (which would also be wrong). I don't get the sense of what you're trying to implement.

Comment: That's not in the number itself that I want to have a comma as a decimal separator, of course, but in the HTML string representations of the JS numbers. In some cases, with the use of some UI controls from some libs, I can't explicitly manage the final string representation of this numbers. So, I was naively looking for a possible way to achieve that without having to manage each case unitarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `toLocaleString();`:

> The toLocaleString() method returns a string with a language sensitive
>   representation of this number.
>
> The new locales and options arguments let applications specify the
>   language whose formatting conventions should be used and customize the
>   behavior of the function. In older implementations, which ignore the
>   locales and options arguments, the locale used and the form of the
>   string returned are entirely implementation dependent.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Just note that it may not be supported in all browsers, or is limited in functionality. You can polyfill it though or handle it manually in those cases:

```
if (typeof Number.prototype.toLocalString === "undefined") {
    // simply make it available
    Number.prototype.toLocalString = Number.prototype.toString;

    // or polyfill/handle here...
}
```

In your case you have to explicitly call `toLocalString()` for this to work. No way around without some hackish approach (**not recommended**):

```
Number.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.toLocaleString(optionsHere)
};
```

Comment: I agree that's how it should be done, but technically the OP said they did not want to have to "explicitly call the `toString()`method." You might want to add an explanation of why an explicit call is necessary.

Comment: BTW the function itself is available in all browsers, just ability to specify a locale and other specific options isn't supported in browsers like Safari.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will accept this answer as it seems to be the best way finally to accomplish my need.

Comment: @Banov for some reason I missed you wanted it for console.log only. This may not work with that as console.log will show the number as-is. In those cases wrap the console.log in a function which calls toLocaleString instead..

Comment: @Ken No at all, console.log was just a very bad example that I used initially in my explanation ;) My need is really general around globalized string representation of JS objects into HTML

Comment: Ok, I'll leave it as it is (my head stopped to work a couple of hours ago anyways.. :) ).