# ASP.NET Core localization decimal field dot and comma

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a localized ASP.NET Core Web Application: en-US and it-IT.

On en-US the decimal separator is dot, in it-IT the decimal separator is comma.

I have this ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public int Id {get; set; }

    // Omitted

    public decimal? Amount{get; set;}

}
```

For the decimal field when I render the create/edit page on **en-US** the html textbox render

> 1000.00

If I POST the form, the operation complete without errors.

So far so good.

When I render the create/edit page on **it-IT** the html textbox render

> 1000,00 (notice the comma)

And IF I try to POST the form, (CLIENT) validation **fail** with

> The field Amount must be a number.

I read about the IModelBinder but I understand is for mapping the viewModel when the form is posted on the server, on my case I'm blocked by the client-side validation.

The better is to use dot when en-US and comma when it-IT, but it's fine using only the dot

Comment: You need to write a script to modify the jquery validator

Comment: Can you give me some other info about this ?

Comment: I'll see if I can find a link for your shortly

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14400739/7880063

Comment: Refer [this article](http://www.stevendewaele.be/validating-numbers-with-commas-with-jquery/#.WaAVoigjHIU) for an example (but you will need to conditionally add it based on the culture)

Comment: @Ravikumar, That is server side, not client side validation

Comment: You can replace the decimal separator, try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12004890/7880063

Comment: Can't you use a string instead and then format it on the server side based on the culture back to its decimal representation?

Comment: @StephenMuecke your tips do the job !. Do you know if I can change the comma with dot on rendering, I would a Plan B if the customer ask for only dot on every localization. Thanks..

Comment: Sorry, not clear what your asking. Do you have some property that identifies what culture that each user wants in the view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After digging depth the problem I found two solution:

The comment from [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) where explain how to add the required jquery to the input for a [validation for comma and dot](http://www.stevendewaele.be/validating-numbers-with-commas-with-jquery/#.WaAVoigjHIU)

A custom InputTagHelper where transform the comma into dot. Here I added only a decimal type but obviously you can add float and double.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = ForAttributeName, TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
public class InvariantDecimalTagHelper : InputTagHelper
{
    private const string ForAttributeName = "asp-for";

    private IHtmlGenerator _generator;

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-is-invariant")]
    public bool IsInvariant { set; get; }

    public InvariantDecimalTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator)
    {
        _generator = generator;
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        base.Process(context, output);

        if (IsInvariant && output.TagName == "input" && For.Model != null && For.Model.GetType() == typeof(decimal))
        {
            decimal value = (decimal)(For.Model);
            var invariantValue = value.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute(new TagHelperAttribute("value", invariantValue));                
        }
    }
}
```

For use this 2nd solution you simply add asp-is-invariant to your input, like this

```
 <input asp-for="AmountSw" class="form-control" asp-is-invariant="true" />
```

Comment: None of them worked for me. When I put 123,00 , post the form and open it again, I get 12300.00 there. This for the first case.
2-nd case didn't work at all

Answer (score 1):

The conversion fails because ASP.NET tries to convert the value with its current culture ([check this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ebe5aks(v=vs.110).aspx)).
You need to set the culture in the current thread of the request. The browser will send the languages it is currently using and supportin with `Request.UserLanguage`.

You can impliment a custom filter, a http module or use the event structure of mvc to set the culture automatically for every request. [Check this link for a sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226514/best-place-to-set-currentculture-for-multilingual-asp-net-mvc-web-applications).

Comment: OP is asking about **client** side validation, not server side

Comment: Yes but even if the decimal input is validated with the it-IT culture clientside the server will return an error parsing the posted string in the wrong culture.

Comment: Not if they have set the server side culture. Again read the question- its  about client side validation

Answer (score 0):

I tried the custom validator that was mentioned above but it wasn't working. I got it to work like this:

```
namespace Project.Helpers
{
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = ForAttributeName, TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
public class InvariantDecimalTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string ForAttributeName = "asp-for-invariant";

    private readonly IHtmlGenerator _generator;
    private readonly InputTagHelper _inputTagHelper;

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for-invariant")]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-format")]
    public string Format { get; set; }
    [HtmlAttributeName("type")]
    public string InputTypeName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public InvariantDecimalTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator)
    {
        _generator = generator;
        _inputTagHelper = new InputTagHelper(_generator);
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {

        _inputTagHelper.Value = Value;
        _inputTagHelper.Name = Name;
        _inputTagHelper.InputTypeName = InputTypeName;
        _inputTagHelper.Format = Format;
        _inputTagHelper.For = For;
        _inputTagHelper.ViewContext = ViewContext;

        _inputTagHelper.Process(context, output);

        if (output.TagName == "input" && _inputTagHelper.For.Model != null && _inputTagHelper.For.Model.GetType() == typeof(decimal))
        {
            decimal value = (decimal)(_inputTagHelper.For.Model);
            var invariantValue = value.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute(new TagHelperAttribute("value", invariantValue));
        }
    }
}
}
```

In ViewImports :

```
 @addTagHelper *, Project
```

In View :

```
 <input asp-for-invariant="numberProp"/>
```

Comment: what is numberProp ?

Answer (score 0):

Comma and dot problem depend on culture and pc language so i solved problem with js like  follow

```
   Amount: { editable: true, type: "number"},
```